# TFS Source Control Causing Me Caching Issues

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I am having this problem where when My TFS Source Control is Online Some of my changes to my .Web project aren't taking Effect.  But when I take TFS Offline Then my changes Take effect.
I am using TFSPreview Which is awesome by the way.  But i really don't understand the issue that I am seeing.  I am very new to TFS I would appreciate the Help

The changes I am making are changes to a .cshtml file.  Simply changing words in it and file refernces.  Litterally removing things and they are still there.

**This will clarify my issue. TFS Source Control has an OFfline mode. If is put myself in Offline mode the problem doesn't occur and my changes appear. If I go into Online Mode My changes do not show when I run the project.**

Answer (score 0):

The thing to keep in mind with TFS is that files under its control are marked as read-only.

You don't mention what types of changes you are trying to make, but if you are trying to change configuration information, for example, and the file is in read-only mode, then your changes will not be made.

Comment: I am simply making changes to a .cshtml File and then saving it and running it.  THe problem feels like when Visual Studio Runs the web project its running it from somewhere else

Comment: Ah. When you run it within visual studio, the default is to run it using the builtin Visual Studio Development Server web server. This does not cause the changes to be deployed to IIS. You either need to deploy to IIS or change the properties of the web project to run using IIS.

Comment: Yea its set to use IIS Express.  This will clarify my issue.  TFS Source Control has an OFfline mode.  If is put myself in Offline mode the problem doesn't occur and my changes appear.  If I go into Online Mode My changes do not show when I run the project.

Answer (score 0):

When you go online mode from offline mode, VS will sync up local changes to server. The way it does is by figuring out which files are not read only.
Lets say someone has locked the file on server to disable checkout, in that case VS will ignore local changes and get the server read only copy. My guess is either you or someone else has checked out the same copy as exclusive. In that case when you go online, TFS doesn't acknowledge your changes and discards them.